# Get values based on variable character position and length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hope you can help me figure out the best solution to this. I have this file with a certain column('RAW') which contains data like this - **STARTNA03N010110FIRST_NAME0211MIDDLE_NAME0309LAST_NAME0501S060829041987070110803PHL090101001M.....END**

Basically after START, a segment for Name details should be extracted. With segment identifier as NA03N01, the 0110 that followed indicates First Name data with 01 as identifier for First Name while 10 is the number of characters that I should take to get the actual First_Name value. Then 0211 is for Middle Name with 02 as identifier of Middle Name, and 11 as the number of characters of actual Middle_Name. 03 is for last name with 09 as the number of characters to get. Please take note that middle name is not mandatory, hence some records won't contain 02XX value.

Notice that there is no 04XX, that is because that pertains to Mother's Maiden Name, which again is not mandatory. 0501S is for Civil Status with 05 as CS identifier followed by 01 which means the value contains 1 character, which turned out to be S (Single).

There are other segments after the Name (NA03N01) like ID(ID03I01), Address(PA03A01), Employment(EA03E01), etc. that is why this particular column has to be parsed correctly. Again, each segment varies as there are variables that are not mandatory.

I tried to make columns based on segments:

`

```
rows_2d = ["NA03N", "ID03I", "PA03A","EA03E"]

all_codes = []

for code in rows_2d:
    for i in range(20):
        all_codes.append(code + ("{0:0=2d}".format(i+1)))
```

`

I also defined a checker:

```
def isInt(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

And the method for separating the actual values:

`

```
def get_next_characters_w_columns(code, string, columns):
    
    done = 0
    output = ""
    
    code_index = string.find(code)
    
    if code_index == -1:
        return "None"
    
    a = code_index + len(code)
    while(done < len(columns)):   
        if isInt(string[a:a+2]):
            fieldNo = int(string[a:a+2])
            temp_output = string[a+4:a+4+int(string[a+2:a+4])]
            a = a + int(string[a+2:a+4]) + 4
            
            if fieldNo in columns:
                output = output + temp_output
                done += 1
                if done < len(columns):
                    output = output + " "
                
            if fieldNo > max(columns):
                return output
        else:
            return output
    return output
```

`
I am calling the method by this:

`

```
def get_info(row, code, place=[i+1 for i in range(35)]):
    if "START" in row["RAW"]:
        info = get_next_characters_w_columns(code, row["RAW"], place)
        if (info == "-1") or (info == "-5"):
            return "No Info"
        else:
            return info
    else:
        return "None"
```

`
This is my output [image]

My real intention is to get the values directly from RAW column (and put them in separate columns - FNAME, MNAME, LNAME, etc.) since the identifiers and length of characters are already there. The second option is to take individual values from each table I generated, but I guess this will pose another challenge since there are values that are not mandatory.

Sorry, this has been a long one, but I hope I presented it clearly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you actually have any issue with your code? I tried to run it and the result looked nice. You would like to have something more direct? Since the content of your raw file is very interconnected, it seems to be pretty tricky to parse differently. Are there more mandatory segments which could serve a regex or some sort of splitting function as an anchor?

Comment: To answer this, yes the codes are running well, but there is a challenge for me as to get  the actual values to respective fields. For instance, under PH03P01 segment, I am getting these values 63 917 7674937 S M Y 24062015 02032021 Y 
Now for me to move forward, I need to get the first two characters as the country code, 917 as the area code and the next 7 as contact number. S is for a defined format with corresponding value, which is not mandatory by the way, and so on.This  is much challenging compared if I will get it directly from RAW column based on regex, as you gave. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) as they allow to extract only certain set/number of characters, or to implement restrictions like 0-1 times a certain pattern.

Update - Approach of Iteratively building up the regex similiar to what your code is already doing:

```
import re
raw = 'STARTNA03N010110FIRST_NAME0211MIDDLE_NAME0309LAST_NAME0501S060829041987070110803PHL090101001MEND'

raw1 = 'STARTNA03N010110FIRST_NAME0309LAST_NAME0501S060829041987070110803PHL090101001MEND'

pattern = r'STARTNA03N01'
segment = r'(\d{2})(\d{2})'
while re.search(pattern + segment, raw):
    pattern += segment
    match = re.search(pattern, raw)
    count = match.groups()[-1]
    pattern = f'{pattern}(\w' + '{' + count +'})'
    match = re.search(pattern, raw)

print(match.groups()[::3])
print(match.groups()[2::3])
# Output
('01', '02', '03', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10')
('FIRST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'S', '29041987', '1', 'PHL', '0', 'M')

# Output for raw1
('01', '03')
('FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME')
```

`count = match.groups()[-1]` identifies the number of following characters to use it for the next regex.
All in all its comparable to your code, just more compact. Also, if you change the start pattern to one of your `all_codes` elements, you should get immediately the corresponding fields.

Update - providing code for my last comments

```
def get_code_elements(code, raw):
    pattern = code
    segment = r'(\d{2})(\d{2})'
    match = []
    while re.search(pattern + segment, raw):
        pattern += segment
        match = re.search(pattern, raw)
        count = match.groups()[-1]
        pattern = f'{pattern}(\w' + '{' + count +'})'
        match = re.search(pattern, raw)
    if match:
        return match.groups()
    else:
        return []
        # alternatively return a result dictionary
        # return {a: b for a,b in zip(match.groups()[::3], match.groups()[2::3])}

raw = 'STARTNA03N010110FIRST_NAME0211MIDDLE_NAME0309LAST_NAME0501S060829041987070110803PHL090101001MEND'
all_codes = ['STARTNA03N01', 'ID03I01', 'PA03A01']
for code in all_codes:
    elements = get_code_elements(code, raw)
    # process elements as you need
```

As I see it your `code`s are all unique and will not be present more than once in your raw string. That means your raw string can be processed as described above.

Comment: Thank you, @Flow. The challenge with this approach is that if there were only few data available. For instance: raw3 = 'STARTNA03N010110FIRST_NAME070110803PHL090101001MEND' Running your code will give an output of '0110', 'FIRST_NAME', '0701', None, '1080', None, None, None which is not the ideal one since 1080 has been grouped wherein it should only be the value 1 for 0701

Comment: Appreciate your help, Flow. I hope it's not too much to ask, but can you please elaborate this _'Also, if you change the start pattern to one your all_codes elements, you should get immediately the corresponding fields.'_

Comment: I am sorry that it was unclear. I updated the answer. Hope that clarifies it. By the way: Why did you loop until 20 in your first piece of code (where you generated `all_codes`)? Does your raw string contain 80 segments?

Comment: The loop till 20 is like a placeholder since there are variable number of segments. For example, depending on the number of IDs that a customer presented, ID03I will have segments of ID03I01, ID03I02, ID03I03, etc. But the code will only get those with values(info) in it. Hope it clarifies. Also, I am getting _UnboundLocalError: local variable 'match' referenced before assignment_ error in _return match.groups()_ Thanks!

Comment: I see. The Error is raised if the while loop is never entered, that means either that your raw string did not contain the provided `code` or that the first regex is missing something. Either way, match should be checked before trying to access one of its methods. I'll update the code.

Comment: If the raw string contains something which should have been found we need to have another look at it.

Comment: Here's the snippet of the actual row: raw = 'STARTNA03N010110FIRST_NAME0211MIDDLE_NAME0309LAST_NAMEID03I010111N04110100980202DL' Using the all_codes = ['STARTNA03N01', 'ID03I01'], your program should have found the 'ID03I01' with elements ('01', '11', 'N0411010098', '02', '02', 'DL) but unfortunately it still gave a _local variable 'match' referenced before assignment_ error'. Thank you.

Comment: I am not that experienced with the re modul myself. I confused re.match (which find only at the beginning of the string) with search ^^'. Sorry about the confusion. And about the error: match is now also initialized. That way, if no pattern is found, the if condition is met.

Comment: No worries at all, you're such a great help. Not sure if I'm missing something though, but running the codes only return the elements for the last 'code' i.e ID03I01. It didn't return the values for STARTNA03N01?

Comment: This is odd. I tried it myself and it returns correct results for both codes with your latest raw string.

Comment: My bad, I figured it out. Anyway, almost there but just one more, what should be the proper way to get even the space and special characters? ,\w is for characters and numbers right? sorry, tried playing around with other special characters but can't figure it out. Really not familiar with regex as well.

Comment: `.` instead of `\w` matches every character except newline according to the [Regular expression documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).